# craps in python

Tags: python, dice

I'm trying to simulate n games of craps.  The code seems to make sense to me but I never get the right result.  For example, if I put in n = 5 i.e. fives games the wins and losses sum to something greater than 5.

Here's how it's supposed to work:  if initial roll is 2, 3, or 12, the player loses.  If the roll is 7 or 11, the player wins.  Any other initial roll causes the player to roll again.  He keeps rolling until either he rolls a 7 or the value of the initial roll.  If he re-rolls the initial value before rolling a 7, it's a win.  Rolling a 7 first is a loss.

```
from random import randrange

    def roll():
        dice = randrange(1,7) + randrange (1,7)
        return dice

    def sim_games(n):
        wins = losses = 0
        for i in range(n):
            if game():
                wins = wins + 1
            if not game():
                losses = losses + 1
        return wins, losses

    #simulate one game

    def game():

            dice = roll()
            if dice == 2 or dice == 3 or dice == 12:
                return False
            elif dice == 7 or dice == 11:
                return True
            else:
                dice1 = roll()
                while dice1 != 7 or dice1 != dice:
                    if dice1 == 7:
                        return False
                    elif dice1 == dice:
                        return True
                    else:
                        dice1 = roll()

    def main():

        n = eval(input("How many games of craps would you like to play? "))
        w, l = sim_games(n)

        print("wins:", w,"losses:", l)
```

Comment: what results are you getting? how many games are you trying to run and how many wins and losses are you getting for that number of games?

Comment: Doesn't randrange(1,7) simulate a seven-sided die?

Comment: @John: No, ranges in Python are half-open, i.e. the 7 isn't included and you end up with `start - stop` = 6 options from `start` to `stop - 1`.

Comment: `random.randint(1, 6)` might be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with

```
        if game():
            wins = wins + 1
        if not game():
            losses = losses + 1
```

Instead, it should be

```
        if game():
            wins = wins + 1
        else:
            losses = losses + 1
```

In your code, you are simulating two games instead of one (by calling `game()` twice). This gives four possible outcomes instead of two (win/loss), giving inconsistent overall results.

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
for i in range(n):
    if game():
        wins = wins + 1
    if not game():
        losses = losses + 1
```

you call `game()` twice, so you play two games right there. What you want is a else block:

```
for i in range(n):
    if game():
        wins = wins + 1
    else:
        losses = losses + 1
```

Btw, you can simplify the logic with `in`:

```
def game():
    dice = roll()

    if dice in (2,3,12):
        return False

    if dice in (7,11):
        return True

    # keep rolling
    while True:
        new_roll = roll()

        # re-rolled the initial value => win
        if new_roll==dice:
            return True

        # rolled a 7 => loss
        if new_roll == 7:
            return False

        # neither won or lost, the while loop continues ..
```

The code is quite literally the description you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this

```
    for i in range(n):
        if game():
            wins = wins + 1
        if not game():
            losses = losses + 1
```

It doesn't work out well at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with this code. Most importantly, you're calling game() twice per loop. You need to call it once and store the result, and switch based on that.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as what the numerous problems are?  I fixed the calling the game() function twice problem, and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: Any call to eval should be treated with extreme suspicion. If you want an int, call int(), not eval. Eval can execute arbitrary code. There are also variables initialized that aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

An OO rewrite:

```
import random

try:
    rng = xrange   # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
except NameError:
    rng = range    # Python 3.x
    inp = input

def makeNSidedDie(n):
    _ri = random.randint
    return lambda: _ri(1,n)

class Craps(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Craps,self).__init__()
        self.die = makeNSidedDie(6)
        self.firstRes = (0, 0, self.lose, self.lose, 0, 0, 0, self.win, 0, 0, 0, self.win, self.lose)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.wins   = 0
        self.losses = 0

    def win(self):
        self.wins += 1
        return True

    def lose(self):
        self.losses += 1
        return False

    def roll(self):
        return self.die() + self.die()

    def play(self):
        first = self.roll()
        res   = self.firstRes[first]
        if res:
            return res()
        else:
            while True:
                second = self.roll()
                if second==7:
                    return self.lose()
                elif second==first:
                    return self.win()

    def times(self, n):
        wins = sum(self.play() for i in rng(n))
        return wins, n-wins

def main():
    c = Craps()

    while True:
        n = int(inp("How many rounds of craps would you like to play? (0 to quit) "))
        if n:
            print("Won {0}, lost {1}".format(*(c.times(n))))
        else:
            break

    print("Total: {0} wins, {1} losses".format(c.wins, c.losses))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```